# Desktop Hosting VS Mobile Hosting (HTML5 Game)

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser, hosting, game-development

I am trying to host an html5 game. I have composed a single html file that utilizes 5,701,046 characters of text to define all of my game logic, level data, spritemaps, DOM interactions, etc. (I do not use any libraries, jquery, json, or the sorts, just vanilla html and js) This html file runs as intended if I open it from my chromebook's file system. It also works if I use new google sites or glitch to host my webpage and open it on my chromebook. However, if I try to open this webpage on my iphone, chrome web browser app and safari both display it improperly, albeit similarly: The html canvases I use are still there, and they respond to events properly, which indicates my file wasn't completely ignored, but nothing draws to the canvas, whether I'm using fillRect() or putImageData() for my spritemaps.

Does anyone know why my phone won't read my html file correctly? Is it a browser issue, an operating system issue, can't keep up with performance? Am I uploading too large of an HTML file from the server? The best I knew how to do for mobile debugging was to look for logs using "chrome://inspect" - and only the logs I was expecting to show up presented themselves. (I would think if I used unsupported syntax in my codebase, some sort of error message would alert me to that?)

So the most mystifying aspect of this problem is that there seems to be no error message alerting me to why a functional html page on one browser/platform suddenly doesn't work on another platform...

I am very new to hosting, servers, and cross-browser/cross-platform testing, but more experienced with front end scripting. I try to avoid third-party code as much as possible. Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: Are the canvas declared in html or just dynamically appended into the page with JavaScript?  Was it hosted for the iphone test? or offline?

Comment: Dynamically appended with javascript. It was hosted for the iphone test.

Comment: It could be the vanilla, I would try the most minimal html and css as possible.

Comment: I think so too - almost all of my code is pure javascript. Even the image data is entirely textual, stored in javascript between <script> tags, essentially taking the form of a Uint8ClampedArray. Seeing as my js was able to establish the structure of the html DOM and listen properly to events, but won't draw anything to canvas, I wonder if the issue resides in the sheer amount of textual image data I define? Does this surpass some mobile browser limit I am unaware of? But if so, why wouldn't I see an error message? Thanks for helping, btw!

Comment: Why Uint8ClampedArray? That could be the problem, try to load it as just a base64 string or load it normally from a file in the same location as the html file.